# OpenURI::open together with Rails can't load JSON from localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

I have such evident controller's code:

```
require "json"
require "open-uri"

class FoobarController < ApplicationController
    def get
        render json: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
    end

    def output
        data = open("http://localhost:3000/foobar/get").read
        puts(JSON.parse(data))
    end
end
```

One controller's action returns JSON, another action downloads and outputs it.

But this code don't work correctly: Foobar#get returns JSON, but open(...) can't load JSON (server don't response).

But for all that when I try to load and parse JSON in this way it works correctly.
And when I try to load JSON from external server in Foobar#output it works correctly too.

But all together - Rails, OpenURI and localhost - break my code. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Webrick (web server that you're using in development env) is written in pure ruby and can only process one request at a time. Because of that your request (from controller) waits to current one finishes.

That produces deadlock, and because of that your requests hangs, of course you do not have those problems with other servers/sources.

### Solution

Alternative to Webrick is [thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/), which can run concuren requests, for more info and usage, check its readme on GitHub.

#### How

Add thin to your Gemfile

```
gem 'thin'
```

Start server

```
bundle exec thin start --threaded
```

Comment: Yes, while you edited the answer, I installed thin. Unfortunately, it didn't solve a problem.

Comment: Have you tried with option `--threaded Call the Rack application in threads` ?

Comment: Now I tried (`thin start --threaded`). Sorry, but problem is still actual.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, btw if actions are in same controller, it seems like an antipattern to have actual request between actions, maybe you can just introduce some layer of abstraction that creates that payload that both actions are retuning.

Comment: In fact in my general project action, which returns JSON, and action, which parses it, are placed in different controller. (In this test application I place actions in one controller just for simplicity sake.) But this problem is actual even in that case.